# Can't-be-arsed as an adjective?

Tags: idiom-meaning

*Can't be arsed* means can't be bothered. It means that one *can't be bothered* to do something. I've seen it being used as an adjective. What could *can't be arsed ice cream* mean?

The original texts says:

> Apple pizza with can't be arsed ice cream.

Comment: Where did you find that sentence? It makes no sense.

Comment: Has someone named an ice cream flavour or type as "Can't be Arsed"?  Beyond that please indicate & quote (or at least link to) the full context of your "original text" - not just a few extracted words.

Comment: It's from the book " Everything I Know About Love". It is the title of a chapter and the first paragraph is provided below thanks to StoneyB. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "recipe given to me by my mum, to impress people when they came round to my crap house for crap dinner parties, requiring zero skill or effort." [Source](http://dl.oceanofpdf.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/oceanofpdf.org-Everything-I-Know-About-Love-Dolly-Alderton.pdf)

Parse it as *can't-be-arsed ice cream*: that is, ice cream which you want to create with as little effort as possible.

Comment: Thank you StoneyB! I think it makes sense now. 